# How to cancel asyncio's loop.call_later()?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, event-loop

If I [schedule a callback using `loop.call_later()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#scheduling-delayed-callbacks) (or with `loop.call_at()`, which behaves the same way), is it possible to cancel its execution?

Why? Let's say I schedule something to run one minute from now. However, due to some condition, the code decides to abort that execution (because it's not needed anymore), or alternatively decides to reschedule it for another time. The question is how to implement it using Python's `asyncio`?

If you are familiar with JavaScript, I'm looking for equivalents of `setTimeout()` and `clearTimeout()`.

Comment: I'd appreciate a comment on why the question was downvoted. I searched for it both online and in StackOverflow before posting. I also tried to be clear and direct to the point and on-topic.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but it's safe to assume that it's due to the fact that the answer is  right in the second sentence of the linked documentation. The downvote tooltip says "does not show research effort", so that's a valid reason for downvoting, although in this case I personally wouldn't downvote because it's clear that research was done - a lazy person just wouldn't bother with including the link! - but the crucial information was missed. Whichever it is, my personal advice would be to just let it go - unfair downvotes are a fact of life on SO.

Comment: @user4815162342, sure, I'll let it go. I just wanted some feedback for the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#scheduling-delayed-callbacks) you linked:

> An instance of [`asyncio.TimerHandle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.TimerHandle) is returned which can be used to cancel the callback.

And from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#callback-handles) of `asyncio.Handle`, a superclass of `asyncio.TimerHandle`:

> **cancel()**
>
> Cancel the callback. If the callback has already been canceled or executed, this method has no effect.

So just call the handle's `cancel` method.

Comment: I looked at the documentation several times, and yet I missed that sentence! Maybe because I expected an active voice ("Return an instance of...") instead of passive voice ("An instance of foobar is returned"). Thanks for pointing it out!